# modeling a world made of cubes

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm creating a world made of cubes, similar to cube world game.
Is there any quick way to create a map made of cubes that looks like this?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, just create your shapes and then use the "remesh" modifier in "block" mode

Comment: @PeterT Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @someonewithpc I was too lazy to make screenshots, find the hotkeys and how to do texturing. Someone else can reap those points if he wants

Comment: @PeterT I did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [PeterT](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16391/modeling-a-world-made-of-cubes#comment23310_16391) said.

Start by enabling the *[ANT Landscape](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape)* addon. Open the user preferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>, got to the *Addons* tab, search for "Landscape". Click on the check mark on the right, if it is not already enabled.

Add a Landscape <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Landscape* like the picture below.
[image: Landscape]
Add a *[Remesh](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Remesh)* modifier to the object. Set the *Mode:* to *Blocks*. Increase the *Octree Depth* to get the resolution of the blocks you want.
[image]

Same Landscape mesh with only the *Remesh* modifier.
[image]

You can add the *Remesh* modifier to any mesh you do not have to start with the Landscape addon.

Comment: Thank you very much . This seriously help me alot .. Before knowing this , i was modeling the cube world mesh by mesh lol.

Comment: For another approach using particles, check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkhARHotjso