# Creating 3D pixel modeling?

Tags: modeling

I envision creating a 3D model but in the pixel art, 16-bit style. Like the old Mario or Zelda games  Not just outlined liked this but the entire model. I searched for ways to do this but i can't seem to find something like this. If someone could help me find a way to do this i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You could make the model normally and then use a remesh modifier to get a voxelated look

Comment: like this? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16391/modeling-a-world-made-of-cubes

Answer (score 4):

If it is a 3D model of a sprite you want, then I have actually made a Python Script / Addon that takes an image and converts each pixel to a cube with a material of the same color.

https://gist.github.com/MrSprite/ff7fda1ec4bf6850d357.  Go here and click the button that says Raw. Then you can right click on the page that opens to download the .py file.

Install it in Blender like a normal addon.

I don't recommend using images over 100x100 unless you want Blender to lag a lot.  Also it takes around 1 minute to generate 100x100 cubes, but only .39 seconds to do a 32x32 image.

Also, if a pixel has ANY transparency it will not be created, so be careful!

[image: Pixel]

Comment: Nice script! :) You might get better performance if you use dupli objects or some other form of instancing.

Comment: @gandalf3 I created it for the purpose of 3D printing or rigid body physics, but I am constantly revising it, and I plan to add a feature to allow instancing of larger images. Thanks for reminding me of that!

Comment: Thankyou so much this helped a lot

Comment: @Blendy37 Make sure to accept this answer so others find it more easily!